# Formula to format "MM/DD/YYYY" and "M/D/YYYY" strings as date in Excel

Tags: excel, date

I have strings in two formats in the Excel column "MM/DD/YYYY" (04/06/2020 etc.) and "M/D/YYYY" (3/18/2021 etc.).

I would like to change them to date. The below formula works only for strings in the format "MM/DD/YYYY":

```
=IFERROR(DATE(
RIGHT(P2,4),
LEFT(P2,FIND("/",P2)-1),
MID(P2,FIND("/",P2)+1,FIND("/",P2,FIND("/",P2)+1)-FIND("/",P2)-1)
),DATE(2021,1,1))
```

How to adjust it to support also "M/D/YYYY" strings?

Comment: So look at what right() does and edit it to match what you need - I would use an if() to select between two formulae according to the length of your input string.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot for better understanding?

Comment: @Harun24hr screenshot of data?

Comment: Just wondering, because you are working with 2 different dates format, how do you know when each one is applied? Just as example: value `12/11/2021`. Is is 12th November 2021 or is it 11th December 2021?

Comment: First numbers are always for months, and seconds are for days. The only difference is that days and months can be written as 01, 02, or 1, 2.

Comment: @SolarMike could you show me how?

Comment: *First numbers are always for months, and seconds are for days.* Then you are **not** working with 2 different format for dates. Are all your dates always `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns For example, I can have one date in two formats: 01/09/2023 and 1/9/2023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me to get expected outout:

[image]

Notice the dates in column A are left-aligned becaused Excel is reading those values as text but dates in column B are right-aligned because Excel read those values as dates:

Formula in column B:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1;4);LEFT(A1;(SEARCH("/";A1))-1);MID(A1;(SEARCH("/";A1))+1;(SEARCH("/";A1;(SEARCH("/";A1))+1))-(SEARCH("/";A1))-1))
```

After extracting date, just apply format `mm/dd/yyyy` to cells and you'll get your desired output

Answer (score 3):

Formula in `B2` is

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"),3,1,2)))
```

[image]

Working from the inside out:

`TEXTSPLIT` to split the string into month, day, year

`CHOOSECOLS` to reorder the strings into year, month, day

`TEXTJOIN` to join those strings with a `-` that will be recognized by the `DATEVALUE` formula

`DATEVALUE` to turn the strings into a date, and it won't matter whether they are single or double digits for month and date.

Comment: Is CHOOSECOLS() a custom function? I don't have it in Excel 2019.

Comment: Ah, only available in Office 365 sorry. Same with the text formulas I believe. Try @Solar Mike's suggestion in the comments

Comment: Also, if you have space to add some columns, you can use Data > Text to Columns with a custom delimiter "/" to split the dates into 3 columns, then use `DATE()` to combine the columns in the right order.

Comment: Data > Text to Columns won't work for me because I have many Excel sheets with these strings to transform.

Answer (score 2):

```
=DATE(
    INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1, "/", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s"), 3),
    INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1, "/", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s"), 1),
    INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1, "/", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>", "//s"), 2)
)
```

Will convert text strings in an MDY type format with a `/` separator into a proper date. You can then format it as you wish.

If you might have other delimiters, nest `SUBSTITUTE` functions to take cared of that.

For example, if you might have either a `/` or a `.`, you would modify the formula to:

```
=DATE(
    INDEX(
        FILTERXML(
            "<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", "/"), "/", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>",
            "//s"
        ),
        3
    ),
    INDEX(
        FILTERXML(
            "<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", "/"), "/", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>",
            "//s"
        ),
        1
    ),
    INDEX(
        FILTERXML(
            "<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ".", "/"), "/", "</s><s>") & "</s></t>",
            "//s"
        ),
        2
    )
)
```

Algorithm:

- Create an XML from the date, replacing the delimiter with the node identifier
- Since we know there will only be three segments, and they are in the order MDY, we can feed those results into the `DATE` function to create our "real date"
- You can then format the date however you wish

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, done this for the 3/18/2023 example:

MID(P2,FIND(".",P2,1)+1,FIND(".",P2,FIND(".",P2)+1)-FIND(".",P2)-1)&"/"&LEFT(P2,FIND(".",P2,1)-1)&"/"&RIGHT(P2,4)

[image]

You can sort out how to check which one you need to use with iferror() and if().

And showing for 03.06.2023:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for 03.06.2023.

Comment: @Kulis it does but without the last . ie "03.06.2023"